# Was trying to rename multiple files in java and encountered the following error:

Tags: java, file, rename

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
        at rename_1.main(rename_1.java:8)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class rename_1{
   public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException{
      String path_to_folder = "C:\\Users\\sara\\fileUP\\test";
      File my_folder = new File(path_to_folder);
      File[] array_file = my_folder.listFiles();
      for (int i = 0; i < array_file.length; i++){
         if (array_file[i].isFile()){
            File my_file = new File(path_to_folder + "\\" + array_file[i].getName());
            String long_file_name = array_file[i].getName();
            String[] my_token = long_file_name.split("\s");
            String new_file = my_token[1];
            System.out.println(long_file_name);
            System.out.print(new_file);
            my_file.renameTo(new File(path_to_folder + "\\" + new_file + ".pdf"));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `if (!(my_folder.exists() && my_folder.isDirectory())) { // Error}` Don't use [underscores](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)
in variable names - only in capitalized constants

Answer (score 0):

Like most methods in `File`, `listFiles()` doesn't throw an exception if it can't read the files, but instead returns `null`. That's documented, and that's what's happening here.

Try the following to see *why* you can't read the contents:

```java
try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(my_folder.toPath())) {
    for (Path myFile : directoryStream) {
        System.out.println(myFile);
    }
}
```

That will most likely throw an `IOException` that tells you what went wrong.